# map based on users ip

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

how to create a users location map based on the ip address. i collect the ip address of users coming to the site and i want to show a map with their location based on the ipaddress that I collected. Is there any map service which is available to use, i am fine if we need to pay anything to have more queries. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are services that offer IP-to-location databases, for example [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity). You will need to keep these databases updated, since IPs change over time. The free versions are of slightly lower accuracy and updated less often. Identifying locations by IP is a low-accuracy affair though anyway, so it might be enough for your purpose. You then just need to output the results on a map, which you can do using, for example, the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html).